# JQUERY Mobile redirect and calinng function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In JQuery Mobile I am using changePage() to redirect back to a previous page, using the following.

```
$.mobile.changePage( previousPage.prevObject[0].id, { transition: "slide"} );
```

This all works fine. What I am having problems with is, if I am trying to clear the HTML elements from the page that I am leaving. using the following -

```
$('#navigation').html('');
```

This does not happen. If I use the correct back button provided in the JQuery Mobile UI such as this -

```
<a href="" onclick="clearNavigation();" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

The onclick being the function to clear the HTML elements... this way works, but the animation is slow. It will first clear the HTML elements leaving a blank page and the redirect back to the previous page. This just does not look smooth. Is there a way I can redirect back and then remove the elements. to seem like I have speeded up the transition?

Thanks
Rory

PS - The function I currently have for clearNavigation() -

```
function clearNavigation(){
     $.mobile.changePage( previousPage.prevObject[0].id, { transition: "slide"} );
     $('#navigation').html('');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but have you tried `jqmRemoveData()` function?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html

> **`jqmData()`, `jqmRemoveData()` (method)**
>  When working with jQuery
>   Mobile, jqmData and jqmRemoveData should be used in place of jQuery
>   core's data and removeData methods (note that this includes
>   `$.fn.data`, `$.fn.removeData`, and the `$.data`, `$.removeData`, and
>   `$.hasData` utilities), as they automatically incorporate getting and
>   setting of namespaced data attributes (even if no namespace is
>   currently in use).

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/